# Unable to get location on Nexus 5X emulator image

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-6.0-marshmallow

Using *Marshmallow (Google Services) Nexus 5X* emulator image, and issuing `geo fix lng lat` Telnet command, I'm not able to get location either from FusedProvider in my app than in Google Maps (it always says "*Waiting for location*").

I have used the new contextual permission model, and granted access to `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, so that should not be the problem (and even in that case, it should work in Google Maps).

On same machine (Windows 7 x64) and *Lollipop (Google Services) Nexus 5* emulator image, I get an immediate fix either in my app than in Google Maps.

Any idea of what could be the problem? I'd like to emulate on latest version available, but location services are essential for my app...

Comment: I'm having this problem too!